# Why does Contains compare objects differently than ==?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Object t = 4;
Object s = 4;

if (t == s) {       // false
}

List<Object> q = new List<object>() { t };
Boolean found = q.Contains(s);          // found = true!
```

In the above code, I am not surprised by `t == s` returning `false`; it's comparing references to two objects and the references aren't the same.

But I am surprised the the Contains is returning true; obviously it's not just comparing object references..it's like it's comparing the unboxed values of 4 and 4..but how and why does it know to unbox the objects to compare them?  I'm trying to understand the bigger pricniple at play here.

Comment: I believe `==` defaults to a reference comparison of where the `Objects` are in memory, and since they are two distinct objects; they have two distinct places in memory. Therefore they are not `==`.

Answer (score 13):

The expression

```
q.Contains(s)
```

is looking for an element of `q` for which [`EqualityComparer<object>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx)`.Equals(element, s)` is true. For boxed primitives, this compares the values.

Answer (score 7):

`Contains`, internally, is using the instance `object.Equals` method to compare the elements.  It is not using the `==` operator.

The `Equals` method is virtual, whereas the `== operator` is static.  This means that the `==` operator will determine which code to run based on the compile time type of the *variable* (and not the object at run time that the variable holds).  A virtual method, on the other hand, is not statically bound.  It determines which overload of `Equals` to run based on the run time type of the *value the variable*.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) documentation:

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.

Answer (score 2):

`Contains` uses `Equals` methods instead of `==` operator.

Comment: Actually it probably uses `EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals`.

Comment: I get that a virtual Equals method (the "default comparer") is getting called to do the comparison..but I'm imagining the method being called in my case must be Object.Equals since the types I'm doing the Contains on are Objects. And if that's the case, how would Object.Equals know to unbox the content and compare them as ints?

Comment: @DeCaf `EqualityComparer<object>.Default` uses `Object.Equals` under the hood.

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett because `Equals` method in virtual real variable type is check on runtime, and that's why `int.Equalt` method is called.

Comment: I get the general gist of this.. what would be a good source of information to understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

`==` uses the type of the variables to determine what equality to compare.

For `object`/`object` it will do a reference equality.

`Contains` will use the `Equals` method which is virtual and may be overloaded to do a value compare. In this case `int` is written as such.

Comment: `==` uses the type of the **variable** and  **not** the type of the objects to determine what method to call.

Answer (score -1):

`Contains` uses `object.Equals(object)`, which for `int`s are implemented so that `4.equals(4)` is true.  `==` with objects on each side uses reference comparison only.

Also of note: `object.Equals(t, s) == true` because [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) uses the instance's `Equals` method if reference equality fails.